# find mySQL duplicates and edit their specific fields

Tags: mysql

I have a table where the important fields are CompanyName and CompanyID.  Right now there are a lot of rows with identical CompanyNames, but their CompanyIDs are unique.  What I want to do is find all rows with exact CompanyNames and take one of their CompanyIDs (doesn't matter which) and apply it to all duplicates.  I'm using this code to find all duplicates:

```
SELECT  `CompanyName` , COUNT(  `CompanyName` ) AS NumOccurrences
FROM  `product_tbl` 
GROUP BY  `CompanyName` 
HAVING (
COUNT(  `CompanyName` ) >1
)
```

What do I need to add to accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: try subqueries UPDATE .... WHERE Company.ID = (SELECT Company.ID FROM ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
UPDATE `product_tbl` `PA`,
(
    SELECT `CompanyName`, `CompanyID`
    FROM `product_tbl`
    GROUP BY `CompanyName`
) `PB`
SET `PA`.`CompanyID` = `PB`.`CompanyID`
WHERE `PA`.`CompanyName` = `PB`.`CompanyName`;
```